# how do I find out which skin Telerik's RADeditor is using by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik

In firebug under "Style" its showing the css file as follows when I hover mouse over RadEditor

```
"http://localhost/myWeb/WebResource.axd?d=WSPnt1ffDvgb4bj2Ii5nA4MecfZdsnZ0wvgLy3HVcihYTy2nMTq7iIu8RlAb7ZMF61e07jisMUNhQZabIxK2kyuxNpeCFqhE3cgnDSm1-Pc1&t=634237829795625000"
```

In telerik:RadEditor tag ..I haven't specified any property such as Skin=Skin1 or whatever..so its using some default skin...In the Skins folder..there's this folder named "Default" that's got images and css files...Is "Default" what it's using ??? now when I change something in the Default skin's CSS file...changes do not reflect on my page...so how do I find out which css its using ??can't figure out nothing from a path like that

**[edit]**

For this Editor mainly 3 css files are being used namely Editor.Default.css,Window.Default.css and ToolBar.Default.css..now when I view page source , I can't find refernce to any of these 3 css files...Also in firebug , under "Styles" where that weird css path is shown, its displaying CSS classes like .reToolbar , etc...now ALL the Skins' CSS files have got this CSS class ".reToolbar" ..so how to find out which CSS file's class is this particular ".reToolbar class" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the skin used by RadEditor by finding its tag, e.g.:

The link tag rendered contains the URL of the WebResource (e.g. the skin css, that is embedded in the Telerik.Web.UI assembly). To make RadEditor use your skin you should set its EnableEmbeddedSkins property to false and then include a  tag with the URL to your CSS file.

There is some more information in the [Telerik Online Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/skinregistration.html).

Cheers

Comment: but I wanna use the default skin only and make changes to that only..just can't figure out which default skin its using..no way to know which Skin URL of the WebResource is referring to ?? I am guessing its "Default" skin only but then when I make changes to Default Skin..they dont reflect on my page...why so ?

Comment: Because the skin rendered by default is embedded in the Telerik.Web.UI.dll assembly. This way, to deploy a web project using the standard skins, shipped by Telerik you don't need anything than the Telerik.Web.UI assembly (no skins folders, no custom Telerik assembly-related scripts, etc.)

To make the controls use custom css you need to register it to the page and switch the rendering of the embedded stuff off.

Comment: So the "Default" skin under Skins folder is NOT the one that is being used ?? Is this "Default" a custom skin only ?? So if I make changes in this Default skin's CSS, they will only reflect on my page if I add Skin=Default attribute in my tag telerik:RadEditor ?? I have like many pages that have got Radeditor embedded in them  using default skin ..now I need to add this Skin="Default" attribute in each and every single !?? Is there no other way out ? no way to override the properties of the Skin in that telerik assembly??

Comment: my RadEditor is inheriting Master page's properties like bg image, and other CSS properties that I dont want it to inherit

Comment: Actually you can override the styles in the default CSS by using a stricter expression in your own CSS, which will override the styles in the css being output from the web resource.